# ¿Cómo puedo convertir una variable tipo float en string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Es una interfaz gráfica con la que se pretende pasar de la forma polar a la forma geométrica de los números imaginarios.

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
>     boton1=Button(ventana,text="Calcular",command=geo_polar()).grid(row=1,column=2)
>
>   File "main.py", line 22, in geo_polar
>     solucion=print("Radio= "+p1+" y angulo= "+p2)
>
> TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
> ```

Este es el código:

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import time

ventana=Tk()

dato1=IntVar()
dato2=IntVar()
dato3=StringVar()
dato4=IntVar()
dato5=IntVar()
dato6=StringVar()

def geo_polar():
    p1=math.sqrt(dato1.get()*dato1.get()+dato2.get()*dato2.get())
    try:
        p2=math.atan(dato2.get()/dato1.get())
        pass
        except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR")

    solucion=print("Radio= "+p1+" y angulo= "+p2)
    entrada.set(solucion)

etiqueta1=Label(ventana,text="Pasar de geometrica a 
polar").grid(row=0,column=0)
entrada1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato1).grid(row=1,column=0)
entrada2=Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato2).grid(row=1,column=1)
boton1=Button(ventana,text="Calcular",command=geo_polar()).grid(row=1,column=2)

entada3=Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato3).grid(row=1,column=3)

etiqueta2=Label(ventana,text="Pasar de polar a 
geometrica").grid(row=2,column=0)
entrada4=Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato4).grid(row=3,column=0)
entada5=Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato5).grid(row=3,column=1)
boton2=Button(ventana,text="Calcular").grid(row=3,column=2)
entada6=Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato6).grid(row=3,column=3)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, el error se debe a que Python jamás realiza conversiones implícitas de tipos. Está intentando concatenar objetos `str` con `float` directamente:

```
"Radio= "+p1+" y angulo= "+p2
```

Para hacer esto debes hacer un casting explícito de `float` a `str`:

```
"Radio= "+str(p1)" y angulo= "+str(p2)
```

ahora bien, la concatenación de cadenas es un proceso muy ineficiente dado que son inmutables, lo que implica que al concatenar hay que crear un nuevo objeto `str`. Es más simple si usas `str.format`:

```
"Radio= {} y angulo= {}".format(p1, p2)
"Radio= {} y angulo= {}".format(p1, p2)  # Solo 3 decimales
```

o también literales de cadena formateados en Python >= 3.6:

```
f"Radio= {p1} y angulo= {p2}"
f"Radio= {p1:.3f} y angulo= {p2:.3f}"   # solo 3 decimales
```

Por otro lado, tienes algunos errores más:

- En la variable `solucion` de la función:

  ```
  solucion = print("Radio= "+p1+" y angulo= "+p2)
  entrada.set(solucion)
  ```

  Primero, `entrada` no existe en tu código, en todo caso debe ser `dato3`.

  Por otro lado, `solucion` almacena el retorno de `print`, que es `None`. Debe contener la cadena para asignarla a la `StringVar`, `print` en este caso no tiene sentido en la GUI:

  ```
  solucion = "Radio= {} y angulo= {}".format(p1, p2)
  dato3.set(solucion)
  ```
- Otro error tiene lugar al pasar la función a ser llamada cuando se hace click en el botón:

  ```
  command=geo_polar()
  ```

  esto hace que a `command` se le pase el retorno de `geo_polar` (`None` en este caso) ya que al usar `()` la estás llamando. Le debes pasar la referencia a la función, no su retorno:

  ```
  command=geo_polar
  ```
- También tienes algunos errores tipográficos en el nombre de las variables `entada5` por `entrada5` y `entada6` por `entrada6`.

Además de lo anterior, algunas cosas que aunque no son errores debes considerar:

- Importar mediante widcard (`*`) es por lo general una mala práctica en Python y solo se debe usar en aquellos casos en los que esté justificado (y acortar el código a escribir no es una de ellas). A grandes rasgos no se debe usar porque se pierde legibilidad en el código al no especificar de forma explícita el espacio de nombres al que pertenece el identificador, puebla el espacio de nombres actual sin necesidad y, derivado de lo anterior, puede causar enmascaramiento de identificadores entre diferentes espacios de nombres, con los consiguientes errores como consecuencia de ello.
- No tiene sentido que hagas lo siguiente:

  ```
  entry = tk.entry(...).grid(row=0, column=0)
  ```

  con ello `entry` no hace referencia a la instancia de `tkinter.Entry` creada (o cualquier otro widget), sino al retorno de su método `grid`, que de nuevo es `None`. Esto hace que `entry` no sirva para nada. O haces directamente:

  ```
  tk.entry(...).grid(row=0, column=0)
  ```

  o si luego vas a necesitar hacer referencia al widget, aplica grid en una línea distinta:

  ```
  entry = tk.entry(...)
  entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
  ```

  Lo mismo se aplica a `pack` y `place`.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior el código puede quedar:

```
import math
import tkinter as tk


ventana = tk.Tk()

dato1 = tk.IntVar()
dato2 = tk.IntVar()
dato3 = tk.StringVar()
dato4 = tk.IntVar()
dato5 = tk.IntVar()
dato6 = tk.StringVar()

def geo_polar():
    p1 = math.sqrt(dato1.get() * dato1.get() + dato2.get() * dato2.get())
    try:
        p2 = math.atan(dato2.get() / dato1.get())
        solucion = "Radio= {:.3f} y ángulo= {:.3f}".format(p1, p2)
    except Exception as e:
        solucion = "ERROR"

    dato3.set(solucion)

etiqueta1 = tk.Label(ventana, text="Pasar de geometrica a polar")
entrada1 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=dato1)
entrada2 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=dato2)
entrada3 = tk.Entry(ventana,textvariable=dato3, width=40)
boton1 = tk.Button(ventana, text="Calcular", command=geo_polar)

etiqueta1.grid(row=0, column=0)
entrada1.grid(row=1, column=0)
entrada2.grid(row=1, column=1)
entrada3.grid(row=1, column=3)
boton1.grid(row=1, column=2)

etiqueta2 = tk.Label(ventana, text="Pasar de polar a geometrica")
entrada4 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=dato4)
entrada5 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=dato5)
boton2 = tk.Button(ventana, text="Calcular")
entrada6 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=dato6,  width=40)

etiqueta2.grid(row=2, column=0)
entrada4.grid(row=3, column=0)
entrada5.grid(row=3, column=1)
boton2.grid(row=3, column=2)
entrada6.grid(row=3, column=3)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Sería bueno para la legibilidad del código que les dieras nombres más descriptivos a las variables, para que a quién lea el código le resulte más comprensible de primeras. Con esto ya puedes continuar para completar la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]